# NiFi UpdateRecord won't update nested fields

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to use UpdateRecord to replace the value of a nested field.  I'm pretty sure I'm following [the documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.UpdateRecord/additionalDetails.html) correctly, but I can only update the values of top level fields, even using `//` isn't working properly.  I have several configurations in my UpdateRecord settings below, but only the last one to update requestObject has worked.

I am sure that my schema is correct because I have used it to transform the XML into JSON without issue.

I have the following:

Input XML file:

```
<request>
    <requestType>BULKRETRIEVE</requestType>
    <requestDomainType>ROI</requestDomainType>
    <systemName>SYSTEMTEST</systemName>
    <location>USA</location>    
    <userInformation>
        <userId>1313</userId>
        <firstName>Some</firstName> <!-- required -->
        <lastName>Guy</lastName> <!-- required -->
        <email>email@address.com</email> <!-- required if phone not included -->
        <phone></phone> <!-- required if email not included -->
    </userInformation>  
    <requestObject>
        <startDate>2019-01-01T00:00:00.000-05:00</startDate>
        <endDate>2019-01-31T00:00:00.000-05:00</endDate>
        <type>ROI</type>
    </requestObject>
</request>
```

AVRO schema:

```
{
    "namespace": "com.organization.somethingspecific",
    "name": "request",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [
      {"name": "requestType", "type": ["string","null"], "default": null},
      {"name": "requestDomainType", "type": ["string","null"], "default": null},
      {"name": "systemName", "type": ["string","null"], "default": null},
      {"name": "location", "type": ["string","null"], "default": null},
      {"name": "userInformation", "type": ["null", {
        "name": "userInformation", "type": "array", "items": {
          "name": "userInformation", "type": "record", "fields": [
            {"name": "userId", "type": ["string","null"], "default": null},
            {"name": "firstName", "type": ["string","null"], "default": null},
            {"name": "lastName", "type": ["string","null"], "default": null},
            {"name": "email", "type": ["string","null"], "default": null},
            {"name": "phone", "type": ["string","null"], "default": null}
          ]
        }
      }], "default": null},
      {"name": "requestObject", "type": ["null",{
        "name": "requestObject", "type": "array", "items": {
          "name": "requestObject", "type": "record", "fields": [
            {"name": "startDate", "type": ["string","null"], "default": null},
            {"name": "endDate", "type": ["string","null"], "default": null},
            {"name": "type", "type": ["string","null"], "default": null}
          ]
        }
      }], "default": null}
    ]
}
```

And my UpdateRecord processor is configured as:
[image: UpdateRecord]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your schema the requestObject field is an array, so you can't specify something like /requestObject/startDate because it is does not indicate which element in the array to update.

I think you should be able to do something like /requestObject[*]/startDate which would say to change the startDate field for all entries in the requestObject array.

Reference docs:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.UpdateRecord/additionalDetails.html

Comment: This was exactly right, thanks!  I should have put more research into my schema, but since it wasn't giving errors I never gave it another thought.